# Problem installing Oracle

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm not an Oracle DBA, but now must install a instance. I use sqlplus to login but all commands return '2'

Why is this so?

Comment: You'd be better off on serverfault or dba.stackexchange.com. If you have the database software installed and are logged into the server as the oracle user, the "dbca" command should get you started.

Comment: Have you checked the Oracle documentation?

Comment: Are you actually submitting the command - terminating with a `;`, or putting a `/` on the second line? It sounds like SQL*Plus is just waiting for the second line of the command to be entered. But as @darreljnz says, read the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/qstart.htm)

Answer (score 0):

First look here [Oracle® Database 2 Day DBA 11g Release 2 (11.2)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/toc.htm), in the Oracle documentation.

If the only thing you want is a running Oracle Instance, create an init.ora file, with minimum parameters and from sqlplus issue `startup pfile=/your/pfile/x.ora`
If the instance is running you can create a database, where the data is stored in datafiles. In Oracle, an instance is just a collection of processes that serves as an interface to the database files.